# Macro that loads multiple datasets that updates and change names?

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

Im working with a database in SAS that updates every so often. I want the macro to automatically load the most recent dataset of a given year. The datasets cover the years 2015-2018 and each year has a different updated version which is stated in the name of the dataset, i.e. 2015_version9. With my current code you need to update the macro manually everytime a dataset change its version and name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can scan through each library and find the max version number, then save those to a single macro variable string that you can supply to a `set` statement.  Here are the assumptions of this solution:

1. Your libraries are named `lib_2015`, `lib_2016`, etc. and follow 8-char libname requirements
2. Your libraries are static for years 2015-2018
3. Your datasets are named `_version1`, `_version2`, etc.

Here's how we'll do it.

```
%let libraries = "LIB_2015", "LIB_2016", "LIB_2017", "LIB_2018";
    
proc sql noprint;
    select cats(libname, '.', memname)
         , input(compress(memname,,'KD'), 8.) as version
    into :data separated by ' '
    from dictionary.members
    where     upcase(libname) IN(&libraries.)
          AND upcase(memname) LIKE "^_VERSION%" escape '^'
    group by libname
    having version = max(version)
    ;
quit;

data want;
    set &data. indsname=name;
    dsn = name;
run;
```

This code does the following:

- Gets all dataset names from each library that starts with `_VERSION`. The `^` in the `like` clause is an escape character that we defined so that we can match `_` literally.
- Removes all non-digits from the dataset name and converts it to a version number, `version`. The `KD` option in the `compress()` function says to keep only digits from the string.
- Keeps only names in each library where `version` is the highest value
- Saves all the dataset names to a single macro variable, `&data`

`&data` will store a string of all the relevant datasets you want with the highest version number for each library. For example:

```
%put &data.;

LIB_2015._VERSION9 LIB_2016._VERSION19 LIB_2017._VERSION12 LIB_2018._VERSION8
```

The `indsname` option in the data step will store the full dataset name of each observation. We're saving that to a variable named `dsn`. This shows where each observation comes from so you can split them out to individual datasets as needed.